# C# Datetime formatting

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know if there is already a build-in C# method that enables me quickly formate a US-culture date (07/22/2009) to '20090722' string.

I am using .NET framework 2.0;

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you already have it as a datetime:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

If you have a en-US datetime string, you can parse it like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("07/22/2009", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

See the section on MSDN on [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) `DateTime` format strings.